# Upgrade from 14.04 to 15.10 wont work

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, 15.10

So here is my problem. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I want to upgrade to 15.10. Ubuntu has prompted me with the new version and asked if I want to upgrade to 15.10. I click "Upgrade" and the process starts. 
After a few minutes I get the following message below:

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

This can be caused by:
 * Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu
 * Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu
 * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command
'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please ignore this, you can not skip betwen normal Ubuntu releases. You can only skip from a LTS to a LTS and certainly 15.10 is not an LTS release. Are you using and PPA, third party repository?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you install 15.10 fresh from the live USB. At the time of installation it will give you an option what all you can do. I would say stay with 14.04 LTS(Long term support). Ubuntu Desktop LTS releases are launched every two years, refer to this [LTS release cal](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS)